# neo4j recursive count of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my project I need to count my node size. Node size is amount of connections with other nodes until depth of 2.
Currently I'm able to do so with two queries:
1. Get ids of all nodes with certain labels:

```
MATCH (n:Target) RETURN n.Key WHERE <some_where_logic_here>
```

2. Use returned list of Keys for count

```
MATCH (n)-[r *0..2]-(b) WHERE n.Key in {keyList} RETURN n.Key as targetId, count(r) as cnt
```

This works however I wonder if I can get same results with only one query? (like sub select in SQL)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
MATCH (n:Target)
WHERE <some_condition>
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[r *0..2]-(b)
RETURN n.Key as targetId, count(r) as cnt
```

Comment: sorry, the example was misleading. I actually need to apply some filters on 1st step

Comment: Edited to include where condition

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do everything with one `MATCH`. For example:

```
MATCH (n:Target)
WHERE <some_where_logic_here> AND n.Key in $keyList
RETURN n.Key as targetId, SIZE((n)-[*0..2]-()) as cnt
```